# How to map cursor data into another cursor? Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How can I map the data present in cursorA into cursorB, being that columns from cursorA are different from cursorB?

Ex.: CursorA = {"columnA", "columnB"} | CursorB = {"cA", "cB", "cZ"}

I want that CursorB act as a facade for CursorA, so when I request, lets say, column cB from CursorB I actually access columnA from CursorA.

### EDIT

I manage a way to do it using CursorWrapper. Basically, what is needed is to override the `getColumnIndex` method so, when the client asks for the column idx he wants, you return the one from your current cursor. The code bellow shows it:

```
public class CustomCursor extends CursorWrapper {
    /**
     * Creates a cursor wrapper.
     *
     * @param cursor The underlying cursor to wrap.
     */
    public CustomCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnIndex(String columnName) {
        if (SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1.equals(columnName)) {
            return super.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
        } else if (SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2.equals(columnName)) {
            return super.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile._ID);
        }
        return super.getColumnIndex(columnName);
    }
}
```

If is there any better way to do this I'll be happy to try.

Comment: Are you trying to make a cursor with column names for search suggestions but using the data from your database?  Please post the SQL for your searchContactsByName query.  I think I can answer your question.

Comment: It is something like that @krislarson , it is not quite for search suggestions 'cause I am implementing a whole new library for that. I've just found out how to do it using CursorWrapper. Unfortunately, as the database is big, the UI is suffering to render the result. I'll update the question with my current solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do your query something like this:

```
"select " + 
ContactsContract.Profile.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " as " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1 ", " +
ContactsContract.Profile._ID + " as " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2 + ","
.
.
.
```

Comment: Neat! It is faster indeed!

Comment: Fantastic! I'd be grateful if you accepted the answer as correct.